# updating and/or creating objects with dynamic forms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

Hi I have a relatioship between client and phones.
Using an array name in the form I managed to save all numbers to a client:

**form:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control phone-number" name="phoneNumbers[work][]" value="">
```

**controller:**

```
$numbers = [];
    foreach(Input::get('phoneNumbers') as $phone_type => $array){
        foreach($array as $index => $phone_number ){
            $phone = new Phone(array(
                'name' => $phone_type,
                'number' => $phone_number
            ));
            array_push($numbers, $phone);
        }
    }

    $client->phones()->saveMany($numbers);
```

But now on to updating... Wouldn't it be better to just remove all phones and recreate them with the new ones? As I'm not sure how to write the script to update the phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete and re-create, easiest way to achieve this (works pretty well, I did it a couple of times for an admin panel).

Comment: Its is indeed easiest, but it seems unprofessional :D

Answer (score 0):

When the phones/numbers are saved to the model, each would receive an id. When you output this to your update form, tag each one with the appropriate id. The input can then update the correct phones. Loop through them same way, finding and updating each.

Comment: But the idea is that you can also add new ones. So at the end I'll be having a combination of name="phoneNumbers[work][phone_id]" and name="phoneNumbers[work][]". Certainly now with the football I can't get my mind straight.